# Click LinkText To Open A activities

Tags: android

In android I have my textview, I type "HELLO I AM **KELLO** I kie **HAMBERY**"
I want when I click on Kello it will pass into kello activity
and when I click on Hambery it will pass into Hambery activiy

Comment: Btw - accept some answers. This is how SO works.. if you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you could use multiple `TextViews` to form your sentence.  Then for the words you want clicked, you could add an `onClickListener` and have that open the correct activity.